# Function that takes two void* and compares them

Tags: c, function

Im having a problem of coding a function compare in a task from my school.

Layout:

```
int compare(const void* s1,const void* s2){
/**
 * Comapares two "entries" based on their votes
 *
 * @return 0 in case if they are same, positive value if first entry is bigger than the 
 * second one, negative value if the second entry is bigger than the first one
 */
}
```

So basically this is how does my task layout looks like. To understand what the entries means, is that they are void* to structures where structure in .h file looks like this:

```
struct student {
    // Name of student
    char name[BUFSIZE];
    // number of votes
    int votes;
};
```

And Im supposed to take this entries and compare them based on their votes. Problem is that void* "value" because I tried almost everything from memory compare functions to try to store this entry into this predefined structure but if I return it, it returns big numbers and basically I dont know how to take theese void values and compare them.

Im looking for any suggestions of how should I proceed in this situation.

Comment: You have to cast the `void *` to a type that can be compared. e.g. `strcmp((char *)s1, (char *)s2)`

Comment: How is that comparison function used and called? What is the *actual* arguments passed to it? Lastly a hint: Read about *casting*.

Comment: It compares two "I think" members in database of students, that are stored in structure as shown. I can provide only example of entry from auto test that tests these functions(there are more functions in my task than just compare): http://prntscr.com/myorsm - screen of entry arguments are in red squares.

Comment: And yes I tried to cast the void to strcmp or anything but it doesnt work because strcmp compares only like string of the enry? I think, it basically was giving me wrong results, because I need to only compare votes and not name of members

Comment: To be able to help you, you must show us how the function is supposed to be used. What arguments are really passed to the function? Please create a [mcve] to show us (by editing the question).

Comment: "I tried almost everything from memory compare functions to try to store this entry into this predefined structure" --> post some of those attempts

Comment: Please check my answer. i edited and improved it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway you should cast `void*` to `struct student` datatype :

**This must be your implementation of `compare` function :**

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

struct student {
    // Name of student
    char name[100];
    // number of votes
    int votes;
};

int compare(const void* s1,const void* s2)
{
    // Votes comparison
    if(((struct student*)s1)->votes > ((struct student*)s2)->votes)
    {
        // s1 vote is bigger than s2 vote
        printf("the first vote is bigger than the second\n");
    }

    if(((struct student*)s1)->votes < ((struct student*)s2)->votes)
    {
        // s1 vote is less than s2 vote
        printf("the first vote is less than the second\n");
    }

    if(((struct student*)s1)->votes == ((struct student*)s2)->votes)
    {
        // s1 vote is equals to s2 vote
        printf("the first vote is equals to second\n");
    }

    // Student name comparison
    return (strcmp(((struct student*)s1)->name, ((struct student*)s2)->name));
};
```

**In the main :**

```
int main()
{
    student s1, s2;
    strcpy(s1.name, "a"); s1.votes = 5;
    strcpy(s2.name, "b"); s2.votes = 2;

    printf("%d", compare(&s1, &s2));
}
```

***About `strcmp` return value :***

This function return values that are as follows :

- if Return `value < 0` then it indicates `str1` is less than `str2`.
- if Return `value > 0` then it indicates `str2` is less than `str1`.
- if Return `value = 0` then it indicates `str1` is equal to `str2`.

[***Try this online***](http://cpp.sh/44a4x)

Comment: Your first example should be `*(int *)s1 > *(int *)s2`. or the compiler might complain, since dereferencing a `void*` pointer is not allowed by the C standard.

Comment: Casts `(char*)` not needed in `strcmp((char*)s1, (char*)s2)`.

Answer (score 1):

At the pointers s1 and s2 there are 2 objects.

Before to compare the objects you need first of all to attach them types.

You must know what types should have those objects that stay at those locations and cast  them to those types.

So, you need to do

```
  TYPE *obj1 = (TYPE*) s1;
  TYPE *obj2 = (TYPE*) s2;
```

and then you can compare them using *obj1, *obj2, etc.

Supposing at those pointers are objects of type `struct student` then you need to do so

```
  struct student *a = (struct student*)s1;
  struct student *b = (struct student*)s2;
```

and compare them using `strcmp(a->name, b->name)` or via `a->votes > b->votes` a.s.o..

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be an `int compare( void *, void * )` function to be passed to the `qsort()` function.

[`qsort()` is a standard C function](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.5.2):

> **7.22.5.2 The `qsort` function**
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> 1
>
> ```
>       #include <stdlib.h>
>       void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
>            int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> 2 The `qsort` function sorts an array of `nmemb` objects, the initial
>   element of which is pointed to by `base`. The size of each object is
>   specified by size.
>
> 3 The contents of the array are sorted into ascending order according
>   to a comparison function pointed to by `compar`, which is called with
>   two arguments that point to the objects being compared. The function
>   shall return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if
>   the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal
>   to, or greater than the second.
>
> 4 If two elements compare as equal, their order in the resulting
>   sorted array is unspecified.
>
> **Returns**
>
> 5 The qsort function returns no value.

Given your `struct`:

```
struct student {
    // Name of student
    char name[BUFSIZE];
    // number of votes
    int votes;
};
```

I would assume that the `votes` field determines which `struct` is "bigger" than the other.

Note that I think "return 0 in case if they are same, positive value if first entry is bigger than the second one, negative value if the second entry is bigger than the first one" is a horribly under-specified statement.  Taken literally, every `struct` pointer passed is exactly the same size, as is every `struct` itself, so strict compliance with this requirement means all your function really has to do is return `0`.  (If this is class work, I'm strongly tempted to advise you to turn that in with the warning you're going to post your teacher's comments back on this question...)

But, assuming you're ranking in order of votes:

```
int compare( void *p1, void *p2 )
{
    struct student *s1 = p1;
    struct student *s2 = p2;

    return( s1->votes - s2->votes );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

I used what you guys commented and casted it to structure like this:

```
struct student s;
s = *(struct student *)s1;
```

And its working properly when I try to acces value of s.votes, I just have one question because I dont understand that pointer before `()`, why does it have to be before `()` and not like `(struct student *)(*s1)`